# How to create mobile application for different OS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, windows-mobile

I want to develop mobile application for my website where users can see the posts on the application. I want to create not only android or iPhone, I want to create it for Windows, Android and iPhone.

I did some research and they say I need to decide what OS to use to use right programming language and its SDK.

The problem begins here. Do I have to rescript the application for 3 OS, Windows Phone, Android, iPhone? What about resolutions? They are different from Phone to Phone and Tablet to Tablet. Is there anything like CSS so we can auto resize boxes, buttons and headers or something.

I'm really confused. Do you know how the other crossplatform mobile applications like  Temple Run, Minion Rush do give the exact same game?

Answer (score 2):

The http://phonegap.com/ is basically a tool that allows you to create your application in JavaScript, HTML and CSS. It can then pretty much process your app to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

well, [this](http://phonegap.com/) is one way, you have everything explained

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.kendoui.com
- http://www.sencha.com
- http://www.phonegap.com
- http://www.xamarin.com (C# compiled to native code on the respective platforms)

I have some experience with Kendo, and I have to say that html5 and css3 together with javascript has not really impressed me as far as native-like feeling of the app. I'd much rather create a native app (Be it xamarin or on each platform individually) to get a smoother experience. Also, styling out of the box on the components from frameworks like Kendo, sencha etc does not look really good (my, somewhat, picky opinion) compared to what you get by default from the native frameworks.

Comment: I did check phonegap and it wants money for private application more then one. I was looking for completely free solution for this but I think I will need another PhoneGap account for future application that I will create.

Comment: You could check out jquery mobile, which is free :)

Comment: I think it is for mobile sites. I'm looking for an app that is downloadable from stores. :-) Also what is difference between public and private application. They say I can create unlimited public application that is on GitHub. Can you change GitHub privacy setting at any time? If so I do only make it public when I have to compile it.

Comment: No, this is not for mobile sites. All of those can be used to create an app for the appstore just fine. Difference is, if you want to create a cross-platform mobile app, you either have to go with xamarin which compiles to a native app _or_ you have to build an html5 based app and wrap it in some package for the app store using phonegap or some similar tool. Easy as pie.